# sqlite database and listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

Okay, I have searched threw here and did not find my answer at all. What my android app is suppose to be doing is get a list from my php & mysql server, then store it on the database on the phone. This all works, and I can even create a listview with the information from my sqlite db. Where I am stuck as a new coder is trying to figure out how to display the information when they click on the listview item that will take them to another page that will show all the details for that listview.

So in short what I want is have my listview, items 1,item 2, item 3 for example, then when they click item 2, it gets the information for item 2 and displays it. Can someone point me in the correct direction, i know i have to use setOnClickListener, but just unsure how to make it look for that certain item.

```
public class Events extends Activity 
{   
// Identifies a particular Loader being used in this component
String event_name, event_time, event_price, event_loc;
static JSONObject object =null;

DBAdapter myDb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.events);

    openDB();
    new PrefetchData().execute();

    // used to refresh my page.
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refresh);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
          openDB();
          new PrefetchData().execute();
      }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();  
    closeDB();
}

private void openDB() 
{
    myDb = new DBAdapter(this);
    myDb.open();
}
private void closeDB() 
{
    myDb.close();
}

private class PrefetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();      
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
    {
        myDb.deleteAll();
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        String json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://www.website.com/test.json");

        Log.e("JSON Response: ", "> " + json);

        if (json != null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                JSONObject parent = new JSONObject(json);
                JSONArray eventDetails = parent.getJSONArray("event");

                for(int i=0; i < eventDetails.length(); i++)
                {
                    object = eventDetails.getJSONObject(i);
                    event_name = object.getString("event_name");
                    event_time = object.getString("event_time");
                    event_price = object.getString("event_price");
                    event_loc = object.getString("event_loc");
                    //event_pic = object.getString("event_pic");

                    myDb.insertRow(event_name,event_time,event_price,event_loc);

                    Log.e("JSON", "> " + event_name + event_time + event_price + event_loc );
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) 
                {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("Json Error", "Error: " + e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {           
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        populateListViewFromDB();
        myDb.close();
        // After completing http call
        // will close this activity and lauch main activity
        //Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Events.class);
        //i.putExtra("event_name", event_name);
        //i.putExtra("event_time", event_time);
        //i.putExtra("event_price", event_price);
        //startActivity(i);

        // close this activity
        //finish();
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void populateListViewFromDB() 
{
    Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();

    // Allow activity to manage lifetime of the cursor.
    // DEPRECATED! Runs on the UI thread, OK for small/short queries.
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    // Setup mapping from cursor to view fields:
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] 
            {DBAdapter.KEY_NAME, DBAdapter.KEY_TIME, DBAdapter.KEY_PRICE, DBAdapter.KEY_LOC};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
            {R.id.item_name};//,     R.id.item_time};//,           R.id.item_price,     R.id.item_loc};

    // Create adapter to may columns of the DB onto elemesnt in the UI.
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,       // Context
                    R.layout.item_layout,   // Row layout template
                    cursor,                 // cursor (set of DB records to map)
                    fromFieldNames,         // DB Column names
                    toViewIDs               // View IDs to put information in
                    );

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewfordb);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the setOnClickListener.
Be sure to use a CursorAdapter and to specify an ID column inside your db.
when you set the `protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)` automatically the id is the ID inside the db. this way you can pass it through an intent and use the id to get back the data from the db.

Hope it's clear enough. Sorry i wrote quite in a rush

from your code simply add

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(
        new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                      //here the id value is what you need to take data from the db filtering by id  
                 }
            }
     );
```

Comment: I think I kinda know what you mean.. I am using a cursor.. here is my code for it. please see my edit for the code I am using to get information from my db.

Comment: Okay, found out where to put that. How do I get the information to pass to the next activity though?     Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ListInfo.class);
             intent.putExtra("ID", position);
             startActivity(intent);

Comment: you should pass the id and not the position to the next Activity.
Once you have done that you can use the id to do a query to your db and get back the data

Answer (score 0):

you should set listeners to your ListView something like this

```
private OnItemClickListener onListItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO YOUR CODE
    }
};

private OnItemLongClickListener onItemLongClickListener = new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
        YOUR_CODE
    }
};
```

those are two types, longClicj and just click, you can use it both or one, its depends on your needs

also on your onCreate method you should set the listeners to your listView

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(onListItemClickListener);
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(onItemLongClickListener);
```